# Uniswap V2 smart contract keeps getting reverted in JS

Tags: solidity, dapps, javascript, uniswap

I'm trying to swap tokens using Uniswap v2 interface.
The code of the contract is [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x2707Df4b78BE95327CB8291986F4763114fC9778#code).

I'm able to deposit Eth to the contract and but I'm not able to invoke the `swapEthForTokenWithUniswap()` successfully through javascript.

```
const swap = async() => {
    const res = await defitry.methods.swapEthForTokenWithUniswap(web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether'))
        .send({from:acc.address, 
               gas: 100000})
    console.log(res)
}
```

The transaction keeps [reverting](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x1172b519e9dd646e2e1194dedbe9a3f3585fea478560e0162a29ac34975239d0) but i can call the function and swap using the writeContract tab on etherscan. I keep getting `Object.TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError`

Answer (score 2):

I assume it's due to the gas limit you pass along. If you look at a [successful transaction](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xc411952d6fdbd322f427347c277309f06f87121672ba450b6f434a1c007334ec), it actually consumed 222,750 gas, so you need to adjust your limit or use the [estimateGas](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-estimategas) function.

One other thing that I noticed, be aware that using `now` inside your contract to use as deadline is a security risk. The deadline timestamp should be passed from the frontend, because `now` will always just be the time when a miner includes the transaction. Also see my [blog post](https://soliditydeveloper.com/uniswap2) for further details.